# Using AJAX to send variable to PHP and retrieve the output using AJAX again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have list like this

```
John
   Jack 
       Husam 
   Koko 
       Rami 
       Loay
```

And i have dropdown list its also has all this names, when i entered the id of Rami for example in URL he make it selected option in dropdown list, i want if i entered the id of Rami in URL make his parent (Koko) selected option not Rami. I build function to get parent id and its work How can i call it from ajax and get parent id of the id i input it in URL

**php**

```
  public function getParentId($childId)
 {
    $statment = $this->db->prepare("SELECT parent FROM `person` WHERE id = $childId");
    $statment->execute();
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $output){

        return $output['parent'];
    }

 }
```

And this my ajax

```
if ($object->getParentId(($_GET['childId']))){
echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type: 'GET', 
url: 'http://test.local/Family.php?action=getId&childId=idd',
data: {'idd' : $_GET[childId]},
success: function(msg) {
 document.getElementById('names').value = $_GET[childId];
  }
  });
   }); </script>";
 }
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com learn about SQL injection first.

Answer (score 1):

I change this part

```
if ($object->getParentId(($_GET['childId']))){
echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type: 'GET', 
url: 'http://test.local/Family.php?action=getId&childId=idd',
data: {'idd' : $_GET[childId]},
success: function(msg) {
document.getElementById('names').value = $_GET[childId];
}
});
 }); </script>";
 }
```

**To this and its work**

```
if ($object->getParentId(($_GET['childId']))){
echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type: 'GET', 
url: 'http://test.local/Family.php?action=getId',
data: {'childId' : $_GET[childId]},
success: function(msg) {
document.getElementById('names').value = msg;
}
});
}); </script>";
}
```